# UILabel Landscape Orientation

Tags: orientation, uilabel

Im trying to change a UIlabels coordinates in landscape orient so i did this. The problem is that it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    label.frame = CGRectMake(377, 15, 42, 21); 
     }
}
```

Comment: When you say "*it doesn't work*", we have no idea what's happening! You need to tell us.  My suspicion is that you should have the `return` statement *last* in the method—before the `if …`.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at your code closely:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // this line returns immediately
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    // and this code never ever hits...
    if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        label.frame = CGRectMake(377, 15, 42, 21); 
    }

    // nor does it return anything (it's supposed to return a BOOL)
}
```

try doing this instead:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        if(label)
        {
            label.frame = CGRectMake(377, 15, 42, 21);
        } else {
            NSLog( @"label is nil; why is that?" );
        }   
    }
    // return a BOOL to tell the view controller to rotate in all cases
    return YES;
}
```

I didn't test this code for correctness, and from what I can tell the only thing that happens is that the label frame will reset to that CGRect in ***every*** case *except* one of the two landscape modes.